# How to match rows and filtering using rows with column values in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, filtering

For example:

I have

```
Name   Code   State  Unit  
John    +2     AZ     3
Mike    +3     UT     3
Mike    +3     UT     4
Jack    +4     KY     6
Jack    +5     KY     6
```

I need to remove lowest unit from dataframe if all the other columns matching

```
Name   Code   State  Unit  
John    +2     AZ     3
Mike    +3     UT     4
Jack    +4     KY     6
Jack    +5     KY     6
```

Comment: all duplicates but first, or just  the last?

Comment: also, that doesn't look like what you've done; `Mike ... 4` is present in the output

Comment: I need the greatest number in 'Unit'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need remove only first lowest value first sorting values and use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.sort_values('Unit')

m1 = df.duplicated(['Name','Code','State'])
m2 = df.duplicated(['Name','Code','State'], keep=False)
df = df[m1 | ~m2]

print (df)
   Name  Code State  Unit
0  John     2    AZ     3
2  Mike     3    UT     4
3  Jack     4    KY     6
4  Jack     5    KY     6
```

If need remove all lowest values you can compare minimal values per groups for first mask:

```
print (df)
   Name  Code State  Unit
0  John     2    AZ     3
1  Mike     3    UT     3
2  Mike     3    UT     3
3  Mike     3    UT     4
4  Jack     4    KY     6
5  Jack     5    KY     6

m1 = df.groupby(['Name','Code','State'])['Unit'].transform('min').eq(df['Unit'])
m2 = df.duplicated(['Name','Code','State'], keep=False)
df = df[~m1 | ~m2]

print (df)
   Name  Code State  Unit
0  John     2    AZ     3
3  Mike     3    UT     4
4  Jack     4    KY     6
5  Jack     5    KY     6
```

EDIT:

If need match all maximals unit per all columns:

```
m1 = df.groupby(['Name','Code','State'])['Unit'].transform('max').eq(df['Unit'])

df2 = df[m1]
```

Comment: Sure, according to my need I have used transform ('max') and "ne" instead of  "eq"